# Two predicates for same property in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a bookingDate attribute, and I am trying to apply two different conditions for fetching based on bookingDate.

```
    NSPredicate *confirmBookingPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookingDate > %@ AND ANY cab.confirmationStatus == 1 OR cab.confirmationStatus == 0", [NSDate date]];
    NSPredicate *cancelBookingPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookingDate < %@ AND bookingDate >= %@ AND ANY cab.confirmationStatus == 1", [NSDate date], [NSDate dateWithNoTime:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:MINUSFORTYFIVEDAYS]]];

    NSPredicate *nilPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cab.@count != 0"];
    NSPredicate *DatePredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[confirmBookingPredicate, cancelBookingPredicate, nilPredicate]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [Trip MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"bookingDate" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:DatePredicate];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_defaultContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"bookingId" cacheName:nil];
```

But its not functioning as expected. I don't understand why. Kindly guide.

Comment: What are you expecting from this? Did you mean `andPredicate` in this case? If you want to match at least on condition you can use `orPredicate`.

Comment: Yes I meant AND predicate, and I want all booking (confirmed/cancelled) which are in future, and only cancelled bookings which are before today's date.

Comment: `confirmBookingPredicate` want a booking date > current date and `cancelBookingPredicate` want a booking date < current date. How can these two conditions satisfy in single entry?

Comment: That exactly is my problem. Is there a way to satisfy these in a single fetch ?

Comment: Why you can't use an `OR predicate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you want all booking (confirmed/cancelled) which are in future, and only cancelled bookings which are before today's date. Try following predicate for that.

```
NSPredicate *futureBookings = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookingDate > %@", [NSDate date]];
NSPredicate *cancelledPreviousBookings = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookingDate < %@ AND cab.confirmationStatus == 1", [NSDate date]];
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[futureBookings, cancelledPreviousBookings]];
```

Comment: Oh God, what was I thinking! (*facepalm)
ThankYou so much.